# Drupal 8 custom autocomplete error 500

Tags: autocomplete, drupal-8

can anybody help me what wrong I did? The server returns Internal Server Error 500. It looks I am not able to get the controller. Anybody can explain me where is my mistake? I think it is in the routing autocomplete path but I am not sure. If it is how can I fix it?
Thank you very much, guys

My form autocomplete form element:

```
$form['field_father'] = array(
        '#title' => t('Father'),
        '#type' => 'textfield',
        '#autocomplete_route_name' => 'cows.autocomplete',
        '#autocomplete_route_parameters' => array(),
      );
```

The module routing file:

```
cows.form:
 path: '/cows/add'
 defaults:
   _title: 'Add a cow'
   _form: '\Drupal\cows\Form\CowsForm'
 requirements:
   _permission: 'access content'

cows.autocomplete:
  path: '/cows/autocomplete'
  defaults:
    _controller: '\Drupal\cows\Controller\CowsController::autocomplete'
  requirements:
    _permission: 'access content'
```

The controller code:

```
namespace Drupal\cows\Controller;

use Drupal\Core\Controller\ControllerBase;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\JsonResponse;


class CowsController extends ControllerBase
{
    public function autocomplete(Request $request)
    {
      $matches = [];
      $string = $request->query->get('q');

      $query = \Drupal::database()->select('node__field_name', 'fn');
      $query->fields('fn', ['field_name_value', 'entity_id']);
      $query->addField('fg', 'field_gender_value');
      $query->join('node__field_gender', 'fg', 'fg.entity_id = fn.entity_id ');
      $query->condition('fn.field_name_value', '%' . $string . '%', 'LIKE');
      $query->condition('fg.field_gender_value', array('bull','ox'), 'IN');
      $result = $query->execute();

      foreach ($result as $row) {
        $matches[] = ['value' => $row->entity_id, 'label' => $row->field_name_value];
      }

      return new JsonResponse($matches);
    }
}
```

Thank you very much

Comment: add the namespace use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request; in your Controller file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the namespace to support the Request $request.

```
namespace Drupal\cows\Controller;

use Drupal\Core\Controller\ControllerBase;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\JsonResponse;
/****this is newly added****/
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

class CowsController extends ControllerBase
{
    public function autocomplete(Request $request)
    {
      $matches = [];
      $string = $request->query->get('q');

      $query = \Drupal::database()->select('node__field_name', 'fn');
      $query->fields('fn', ['field_name_value', 'entity_id']);
      $query->addField('fg', 'field_gender_value');
      $query->join('node__field_gender', 'fg', 'fg.entity_id = fn.entity_id ');
      $query->condition('fn.field_name_value', '%' . $string . '%', 'LIKE');
      $query->condition('fg.field_gender_value', array('bull','ox'), 'IN');
      $result = $query->execute();

      foreach ($result as $row) {
        $matches[] = ['value' => $row->entity_id, 'label' => $row->field_name_value];
      }

      return new JsonResponse($matches);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Really it works. So the problem is resolved.
Just I'd like to repeat it - I missed to add the Request namespace:

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

Thanks, @vishwa!